# mysql between date with secific data record

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have table material :

```
id_lh : int
usr: varchar 
pas: varchar  
pefil: varchar
date_operation : datetime
```

And i have this data :

```
    id_lh   |   usr         |   pas         |   pevil   |   wkt
1           |   admin       |   admin       |   admin   |   2018-06-18 23:39:51
2           |   s           |   1           |   staff   |   2018-06-20 23:40:01
3           |   s           |   1           |   staff   |   2018-06-21 08:24:30
4           |   admin       |   admin       |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:25:05
5           |   a           |   1           |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:27:37
6           |   a           |   1           |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:28:10
7           |   a           |   1           |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:32:51
8           |   a           |   1           |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:37:35
9           |   admin       |   admin       |   admin   |   2018-06-21 08:45:42
```

i want to execute this query `SELECT id_lh, usr, pevil, wkt FROM tb_log_histo WHERE  usr= 'admin' AND pevil= 'admin' AND wkt BETWEEN '2018/06/20' AND '2018/06/21' ORDER BY wkt ASC` and the result is zero(no record showing) with no error

and then i change the query, `SELECT id_lh, usr, pevil, wkt FROM tb_log_histo WHERE  usr= 'admin' AND wkt BETWEEN '2018-06-20' AND '2018-06-21' ORDER BY wkt ASC` it's the same, not showing with no error too

but if i exeute this query `SELECT id_lh, usr, pevil, wkt FROM tb_log_histo WHERE  usr= 'admin' AND pevil= 'admin' ORDER BY wkt ASC` it will show the record i dont want to show

my question is, how to get the record from this query `SELECT id_lh, usr, pevil, wkt FROM tb_log_histo WHERE  usr= 'admin' AND pevil= 'admin' AND wkt BETWEEN '2018/06/20' AND '2018/06/21' ORDER BY wkt ASC`?

Answer (score 0):

Your wkt field is timestamp so put time in query and you will get result. use below query.

```
SELECT id_lh, usr, pevil, wkt FROM tb_log_histo WHERE  usr= 'admin' AND wkt BETWEEN '2018-06-20 00:00:00' AND '2018-06-21 23:59:59' ORDER BY wkt ASC
```